# How to merge multiple request into one request object in express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have multiple request objects coming to my backend endpoint at different instant of time [interval of few sec]. I need to merge these request object into one. How can I achieve this expressjs?
The reason I want one request obj is because I need user info from one object and user question from another request.

Comment: If anyone looking for Nodejs API boilerplate with Expressjs and MongoDB. Try this: 
https://github.com/maitraysuthar/rest-api-nodejs-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Correlation ID (aka Transit ID) to each of these requests on a side of a client. You can use a random string as an ID, for example, UUID v4. Then on the backend side, you can use this ID to save parts of the data into a key-value store and use the whole collection once required. I would suggest using a key-value store with an automatic expiration to wipe out old unused records.